# Firefox loads, but won't load websites, after crash

Tags: firefox, crash, system-recovery

I use Firefox 58.0 on GNU/Linux Mint 18.3.

I've experienced a few crashes today followed by reboots. At some point, when the system came back up, Firefox opened all previous tabs, but nothing was visible in them, and it was intermittently un-responsive.

- I tried restarting it with no restoration and just typing in a URL - same behavior. It's ignores the typed-in URL and the pane remains empty.
- I tried deleting `~/.cache/mozilla` - same behavior.
- I tried deleting both `~/.cache/mozilla` *and* `~/.mozilla` - same behavior.

What's going on and how can I fix this?

PS - Chromium works fine, so it's not some network inaccessibility issue.

Notes:

- My kernel version is 4.13.0-32-generic.
- My NVIDIA drivers seem not to be loaded for some reason

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `/var` was entirely full, and when I cleared some space in it, Firefox started working again. Sloppy coding on Mozilla's part if you ask me.

Comment: "Sloppy coding" Not really. You cannot expect every application to check whether `/var` is full before writing to it ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: If an app can't do something (probably - open a file or write to it) because it's out of disk space, it should tell the user "out of disk space" or at least "error - see log for details" or even just "failure doing XYZ" - not stop responding. That's why I call it sloppy coding. Probably somebody didn't bother to check their exceptions, or return values, or what-not.